# Please help me to understand these 2 conversations

Tags: meaning

please kindly help me to interpret these 2 conversations:

1)
Mom: Daniel? Are you talkin' while I'm talkin'? That's probably why your behind
is always unemployed. Who gets fired on a day off?
Her son: No!
It's because I don't have any skills.
Mom: True that.
His nephew: You sure told her. (sarcastic tone)
Her Son: I did.
--> You sure told her (sarcastic tone), does it mean that he just proved to his mother he doesn't have any skills.

2)
Mom: How can you create a dating app for Christian singles when you are still single? Baby, you need to stop bein' so picky and swipe left for yourself!
Her daughter: Actually, it's up.

--> Swipe left (I guess it's referring to common practice in dating apps of swiping in certain directions to indicate attraction to a potential match)?
And it's up here (I guess referring to swiping direction in the app, up being the direction of God for the "Christian singles" the app is targeted towards)

What do you guys think?

Comment: Apparently ["swipe left"](https://www.howtogeek.com/702931/what-do-swipe-left-and-swipe-right-mean/) is slang from the Tinder online dating mobile app community. (I had to Google this... I have a [brick and mortar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_and_mortar) wife myself.) I'm not sure how "swipe up" would fit in.

Comment: What is the source of these conversations?  Are they from a movie or from real life? What is the context? Who are the speakers? Where are they from? How do they know each other?

Comment: If there is no connection between the conversations it is better to ask them as two questions.  You could edit and cut question 2, then paste it into a new question.

Comment: Hi James, the dialogues are actually from the movie. They're family members talking. I have revised the source, maybe it will help you to have a better picture.

Comment: I would understand "You sure told her!" to imply that Daniel expressed his opinion to his mother in a very emphatic way, perhaps rudely so (hence the sarcasm). BTW, you still haven't told us _what_ movie the dialogues are from!

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a confirmation. They told her. They did tell her.
2. There is a popular dating app where you are shown profiles of participants and you swipe left if you don't like them. "Swipe left for yourself" could mean "lower the bar", "stop being arrogant", "stop being picky". I am not sure how idiomatic it is -  I have heard *swipe right/left **on** someone*.